# How to split values after each space from the end in SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to extract values from a string which I want to read from the end and get everything from first and second space.

My data values have the following examples:

> FILMTABL FL. 250MG 70
>
> FILMTABL 250MG 70

And, I want the data to be split as

```
Col1        | Col2 | Col3 | Col4    
FILMTABL FL.|250   |MG    |70    
FILMTABL    |250   |MG    |70
```

**DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE(MY_COL CHAR(50));
```

**DML:**

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
SELECT 'FILMTABL FL. 250MG 70'
UNION
SELECT 'FILMTABL 250MG 70';
```

Comment: I see you have worked with regular expressions before (post history). What have you tried in this occasion, and how did it work?

Comment: Hello @FelipeHoffa - I tried TRIM(RIGHT(MY_COL, 3))::INT to start off with but this doesn't give me the right results every time.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to my question. But if anyone posts a better answer, I will mark that as answer for this question.

```
SELECT REPLACE(REVERSE(SPLIT_PART(REVERSE(PACK), ' ', 2)), 'MG', '') AS Col2, REPLACE(REVERSE(SPLIT_PART(REVERSE(PACK), ' ', 1)), 'MG', '') AS Col4;
```